# Duplicate zip entry

Tags: android, gradle

After updating to Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle 3.3 I've started recieving errors when I generate signed APK:

```
Error:java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbqv.class]
```

After upgrading I've added these dependencies:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

My build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 22
        versionName "0.3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

rules are:

```
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
# -keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod

-keep class xxxx.FirebaseModels.** { *; }

# Basic ProGuard rules for Firebase Android SDK 2.0.0+
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
```

Previous version still generates APKs without errors.

Please, help me find solution of this issue.

Comment: Is that the full error message, nothing else is output by gradle? By the way, the duplicate com.android.support:support with different versions is intended?

Comment: @asettouf there was nothing significant except this error message. I've added those librariues because android studio kept writing me "all com.android.support must use exact the same version" and in was mentining both version v4 and v13 (this one was not included in my old build.gradle). I've decided to try using old build.gradle once again and apk generated without errors but now I have this warning about using the same version...

Comment: Right now iI get this: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.2.0, 25.1.0, 24.0.0. Examples include 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0' and 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.0'. Funny thing is that I don't have 25.1.0 and 24.0.0 libraries in build.gradle.